# Angular 4 not working on Tizen Smart TV

Tags: angular, tizen

I created a simple Angular4 app, packaged it as a Tizen web app. This app works across all major browsers that I tested (Safari, Chrome and Firefox) but renders an empty page with an empty () element.

No Javascript errors are showing on the console when running the Tizen app in debug mode. Also Javascript alerts after the Angular4 included files are running just fine.

Another thing I noticed is that Tizen is taking about 10 minutes to compile the javascript code that is generated by Angular (vendor.js is 240kb).

Comment: I am very curious about this. Afaik the packaging doesn't compile anything (you can view the files in the .wgt which is an archive) but creates meta-data and a verification hash. If you find out why the packaging takes so long for you,  post a comment please. This is rather interesting.

Comment: @KVNSTOBJEKT Tizen Studio IDE has some JS auto-checkers. Although I decreased the time by disabling on JS handlers, it was still taking time. However, it packages super fast if you use CLI. There is no code check. It packages our app within a sec by using CLI, otherwise it takes 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You need check polyfills file. This is my file

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
// import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
// import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
 **/
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; // Included with Angular CLI.

/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set **target** to **es5** in the **tsconfig.js** file. Then your Angular app works at least in Tizen 3.0 and newer.

Tizen Studio is buggy app. If you are using Tizen Studio I recommend instead to use **vscode** and [vscode extension](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/extension-libraries/vscode-extension.html) of Tizen TV or Tizen command line interface (CLI). They works well. Vscode also supports type script as well.

[Tizen TV app](https://github.com/heaven-dev/tv7SamsungNg) implemented using Angular 11.

Comment: Tizen TV app link shows 404. :(

Comment: @SyamkumarS did you find something ?